# Markdown editor for Linux with live preview and line break with enter

Tags: linux, markdown, editor

I'm looking for a markdown editor for Linux, which supports

- live preview
- creating a line break with enter (per default MarkDown requires creating a linebreak with a double space at the end of the line, which I find very cumbersome)

Currently I'm using [Retext](https://github.com/retext-project/retext), which is a good editor, but only satisfies the first requirement

Comment: While waiting for answers, maybe you want to check out [these](/search?q=markdown+editor+linux+answers%3A1)? If one of those candidates matches your needs, you could even [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Typora](https://typora.io/) is an otherwise great live markdown editor that lets you insert a paragraph break on Enter and single linebreak on Shift+Enter, without double whitepace needed. Perhaps that's good enough?